# scss colors don't apply in storybook

Tags: reactjs, sass, tailwind-css, vite, storybook

I have a react ts project created with **vite** and **tailwindcss**, I customized theme with **scss**, the problem is that scss styles do not apply in stories.

the main.ts file:

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-vite";
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    '@storybook/addon-designs',
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-vite",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
};
export default config;
```

the preview.ts file:

```
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import "../src/theme/style.scss"

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;
```

the style.scss file:

```
@import url("../assets/fonts/index");
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
}

html[data-theme="light"] {
  // primary -> 800
  --primary-100-color: #fbfcff;
  --primary-200-color: #eef3fe;
  --primary-300-color: #e4ecfc;
  --primary-400-color: #c8d8fa;
  --primary-500-color: #91b0f4;
  --primary-600-color: #5c8af0;
  --primary-700-color: #3b73ed;
  --primary-800-color: #2563eb;
  --shadow-s: 0px 4px 8px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

html[data-theme="dark"] {
  // primary -> 800
  --primary-100-color: #2a2b2e;
  --primary-200-color: #292f3b;
  --primary-300-color: #283144;
  --primary-400-color: #26375f;
  --primary-500-color: #224695;
  --primary-600-color: #1f54ca;
  --primary-700-color: #1c5ce9;
  --primary-800-color: #1b62ff;
  --shadow-s: 0px 4px 8px -2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
}

.th {
  &-text-color {
    color: var(--text-color);
  }
  &-bg-color {
    background-color: var(--background-color);
  }
  &-card-bg-color {
    background-color: var(--card-bg-color);
  }
  &-border-color {
    border-color: var(--border-color);
  }
  &-alert-e-color {
    background-color: var(--alert-e-color);
  }
  &-alert-i-color {
    background-color: var(--alert-i-color);
  }
  &-alert-s-color {
    background-color: var(--alert-s-color);
  }
  &-alert-w-color {
    background-color: var(--alert-w-color);
  }
  &-alert-e-text-color {
    color: var(--alert-e-text-color);
  }
  &-alert-w-text-color {
    color: var(--alert-w-text-color);
  }
  &-alert-s-text-color {
    color: var(--alert-s-text-color);
  }
  &-alert-i-text-color {
    color: var(--alert-i-text-color);
  }
  &-bg-card-to-card {
    background-color: var(--bg-card-to-card);
  }
  &-bade-outline-color {
    border: var(--bade-outline-color);
  }
  &-primary-color {
    color: var(--primary-color);
  }
  &-primary-bg-color {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
  }
  &-primary-border-color {
    border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
  }
  &:hover {
    background-color: var(--primary-color-hover);
  }
}

#root {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  max-width: none !important;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  /* border-radius: 10px; */
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #0c78b4;
}

body > iframe {
  /* display: none; */
  pointer-events: none;
}

body > iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}

body {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  background: var(--background-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  // background-image: url("../assets/images/back.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  // @apply bg-[#FAFAFA];
}
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  darkMode: ["class", '[data-mode="dark"]'],
  theme: {
    fontSize: {
      // singleLine: {
      h1: [
        "26px",
        {
          lineHeight: "40px",
          fontWeight: "700",
        },
      ],
      h2: [
        "24px",
        {
          lineHeight: "24px",
          fontWeight: "700",
        },
      ],
      h3: [
        "20px",
        {
          lineHeight: "24px",
          fontWeight: "700",
        },
      ],
      h4: [
        "18px",
        {
          lineHeight: "24px",
          fontWeight: "700",
        },
      ],
      h5: [
        "16px",
        {
          lineHeight: "24px",
          fontWeight: "700",
        },
      ],
      Label01: [
        "16px",
        {
          lineHeight: "24px",
          fontWeight: "600",
        },
      ],
      Label02: [
        "14px",
        {
          lineHeight: "20px",
          fontWeight: "600",
        },
      ],
      Label03: [
        "12px",
        {
          lineHeight: "16px",
          fontWeight: "600",
        },
      ],
      Label04: [
        "10px",
        {
          lineHeight: "16px",
          fontWeight: "600",
        },
      ],
      Button01: [
        "16px",
        {
          lineHeight: "24px",
          fontWeight: "700",
        },
      ],
      Button02: [
        "14px",
        {
          lineHeight: "20px",
          fontWeight: "700",
        },
      ],
      Button03: [
        "12px",
        {
          lineHeight: "20px",
          fontWeight: "700",
        },
      ],
      Body01: [
        "16px",
        {
          lineHeight: "24px",
          fontWeight: "600",
        },
      ],
      Body02: [
        "14px",
        {
          lineHeight: "20px",
          fontWeight: "600",
        },
      ],
      Caption: [
        "12px",
        {
          lineHeight: "16px",
          fontWeight: "600",
        },
      ],
      Overline: [
        "10px",
        {
          lineHeight: "16px",
          fontWeight: "300",
        },
      ],
      // },
      multiLine: {
        h1: [
          "26px",
          {
            lineHeight: "64px",
            fontWeight: "700",
          },
        ],
        h2: [
          "24px",
          {
            lineHeight: "64px",
            fontWeight: "700",
          },
        ],
        h3: [
          "20px",
          {
            lineHeight: "48px",
            fontWeight: "700",
          },
        ],
        h4: [
          "18px",
          {
            lineHeight: "48px",
            fontWeight: "700",
          },
        ],
        h5: [
          "16px",
          {
            lineHeight: "48px",
            fontWeight: "700",
          },
        ],
        Label01: [
          "16px",
          {
            lineHeight: "48px",
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
        ],
        Label02: [
          "14px",
          {
            lineHeight: "48px",
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
        ],
        Label03: [
          "12px",
          {
            lineHeight: "40px",
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
        ],
        Label04: [
          "10px",
          {
            lineHeight: "32px",
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
        ],
        Button01: [
          "16px",
          {
            lineHeight: "40px",
            fontWeight: "700",
          },
        ],
        Button02: [
          "14px",
          {
            lineHeight: "36px",
            fontWeight: "700",
          },
        ],
        Button03: [
          "12px",
          {
            lineHeight: "32px",
            fontWeight: "700",
          },
        ],
        Body01: [
          "16px",
          {
            lineHeight: "40px",
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
        ],
        Body02: [
          "14px",
          {
            lineHeight: "32px",
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
        ],
        Caption: [
          "12px",
          {
            lineHeight: "32px",
            fontWeight: "600",
          },
        ],
        Overline: [
          "10px",
          {
            lineHeight: "24px",
            fontWeight: "300",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    colors: {
      primary: {
        100: "var(--primary-100-color)",
        200: "var(--primary-200-color)",
        300: "var(--primary-300-color)",
        400: "var(--primary-400-color)",
        500: "var(--primary-500-color)",
        600: "var(--primary-600-color)",
        700: "var(--primary-700-color)",
        800: "var(--primary-800-color)",
      },
    },
    boxShadow: {
      s: "var(--shadow-s)",
    },
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        "01": "0px",
        "02": "2px",
        "03": "4px",
        "04": "6px",
        "05": "8px",
        "06": "10px",
        "07": "12px",
        "08": "14px",
        "09": "16px",
        10: "24px",
        11: "32px",
        12: "40px",
        13: "48px",
        14: "56px",
        15: "64px",
        16: "72px",
        17: "80px",
        18: "88px",
        19: "96px",
        20: "104px",
      },
      borderRadius: {
        xs: "4px",
        s: "8px",
        m: "12px",
        l: "16px",
        xl: "800px",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I also have these dev dependencies in package.json

```
   "@storybook/addon-designs": "^7.0.7",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "7.6.6",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "7.6.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "7.6.6",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "1.0.10",
    "@storybook/blocks": "7.6.6",
    "@storybook/react": "7.6.6",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "7.6.6",
    "@storybook/test": "7.6.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.15",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "storybook": "7.6.6",
    "vite": "^5.0.7"
```

I've tried all ways written on docs but they still don't work.
(story book doc says that with using vite I just need to import scss file in preview.ts, but that is not working)
my main problems are with colors, non of custom colors apply in storybook
I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't define data-theme in storybook html file
after creating the preview-head.html file, question solved

```
    <link rel="preload" href="../src/assets/fonts/YekanXVF.woff2" />
<html lang="en" data-theme="light">
   <link href="../dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</html>
```